# Changing the teletype font to custom font family does not work?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf, fontfamily

I'm trying to change the default teletype font `\texttt` to `courier new` using the corresponding `.ttf` file and `\newfontfamily`. Unfortunately, no matter what combination of commands I try, using `\renewcommand` does not update the teletype font to my desired font. Note that I cannot use `pdflatex` or the `courier` package because I'm compiling with XeLaTeX and have to use `fontspec`.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\courier}{CourierNew}
    [Extension=.ttf, 
     Path=res/fonts/CourierNew/, 
     UprightFont = CourierNew-Regular]

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{\courier}
```

If I use `courier` instead of `\courier`, it replaces the teletype font with a (default) serif font, and using `\courier` simply fails to compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `\setmonofont`. but of course you need to have the font you calla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need install Courier New to your system or put `cour.ttf`, `couri.ttf`, `courbi.ttf` and `courbd.ttf` to `res/fonts/CourierNew/`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Courier New}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
% \setmonofont{cour.ttf}[
% Path            = res/fonts/CourierNew/,
% Scale           = MatchUppercase,
% BoldFont        = courbd.ttf,
% ItalicFont      = couri.ttf,
% BoldItalicFont  = courbi.ttf,
% SlantedFont     = couri.ttf,
% BoldSlantedFont = courbi.ttf]
\begin{document}
Test \texttt{Test}
{\bfseries Test \texttt{Test}}
{\itshape Test \texttt{Test}}
{\bfseries\itshape Test \texttt{Test}}
\end{document}
```

[image]